# Issue with onsubmit not allowing action to send

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html form that runs a script to check if the inputs are empty, and if so, it will not submit and it will send an alert. But when the inputs are correct, I want it to go to my contact.php action. It's running the script correctly but its not activating or sending the data to my contact.php. It's running the script correctly but only the script.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="form.js"></script>
        <form name="Form" onsubmit="return formValidate(event)" action="contact.php" method="post">
            <label>Name:<span id="label_name"></span></label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br/>
            <label >Email:<span id="label_email"></span></label>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br/>
            <label >Subject:<span id="label_subject"></span></label>
            <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject"><br/>
            <label >Email:<span id="label_message"></span></label>
            <input type="text" id="message" name="message"><br/>
            <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

form.js

```
function formValidate(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var name = document.forms["Form"]["name"].value;
    var email = document.forms["Form"]["email"].value;
    var subject = document.forms["Form"]["subject"].value;
    var message = document.forms["Form"]["message"].value;
    if (name == "" || email == "" || subject == "" || message == "") {
      output = "*";
      alert('Fill out all required inputs');
      return false;
    } else {
        alert('Thanks for contacting me!')
    }
    return true;
    document.getElementById("label_name").innerHTML = output;
    document.getElementById("label_email").innerHTML = output;
    document.getElementById("label_subject").innerHTML = output;
    document.getElementById("label_message").innerHTML = output;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `return true/false`, use your conditions to decide whether to call `event.preventDefault`. I don't think it actually matters what you return.

Normally, people write that as the first line because they're going to submit the data in a different way, like AJAX. If you're doing a normal full-page submit, then you don't want to prevent the normal behavior of submitting.

Comment: See your lines where you write `return true` / `return false`? Replace those with `event.preventDefault`. You will also need to do some other things to allow for the function execution flow to proceed correctly. But, I don't fix people's code for them - I just explain what to do to fix it.